# Join two tables where value in second table has value not equal to specific number

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to get all the rows in the flow_definition table where non of the corresponding rows in the flow_permission table have a FLOW_PERMISSION_FK of 4. The following query gets me close:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fd FROM FlowDefinition fd LEFT JOIN fd.permissions p WHERE p.flowPermissionFk <> 4
```

However, all of the rows in flow_permission need to have a FLOW_PERMISSION_KEY of 4 in order for that row to not be returned.

There is one row in the database that has two permissions, one with FLOW_PERMISSION_FK = 1 and one with FLOW_PERMISSION_FK = 4 however that row is still being returned unless I set the FLOW_PERMISSION_FK in both permission rows to 4.

I am also using Hibernate inside of a Spring Boot app but I believe the SQL is more or less the problem here.

Comment: How can a row have 2 values for the same column?

Comment: There are multiple rows in the permissions table that match the foreign key for the FlowDefinition.